# Cannot save data into database retrieve from Server

Tags: android

```
public class DataController extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject> {
    ProgressDialog login_show;
    private Context context;
    private Route_planDataSource rds;

    private final static String TAG = "DataController";

    public DataController(Context context) {
        this.context = context;

    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        rds = new Route_planDataSource(context);

    }

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) {

        JSONObject object = JSONParser.getJSONFromUrl(URL.getRoutePlan,
                params[0]);

        return object;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        JSONArray jArray;
        try {
            rds.open();
            jArray = result.getJSONArray("routePlan");
            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {



                JSONObject jo = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                Log.i(TAG, "VALUES" + jo.getString("terratory_id").toString());
                Log.i(TAG, "VALUES" + jo.getString("target_st_date"));
                Log.i(TAG, "VALUES" + jo.getString("territory_name"));
                rds.createRoute_plan(1, "", "");
                rds.createRoute_plan(jo.getLong("terratory_id"),
                        jo.getString("target_st_date"),
                        jo.getString("territory_name"))                }
            rds.close();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Log.i("dfdf", rds.getAllRoute_plan().toString());

    }
}
```

**Database**

```
public class Route_planDataSource {
    private SQLiteDatabase database;
    private CLSQLiteHelper dbHelper;
    private int openedConnections = 0;
    private String[] allColumns = { TableDEtails.COLUMN_ID_ROUTE_PLAN_ID_AND,
            TableDEtails.COLUMN_ID_ROUTE, TableDEtails.COLUMN_ROUTE_NAME,
            TableDEtails.COLUMN_ROUTE_PLAN_DATE };

    public Route_planDataSource(Context context) {
        dbHelper = new CLSQLiteHelper(context);
    }

    public void open() throws SQLException {
        database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
          openedConnections++;
    }



    public   void close() {


           dbHelper.close();

    }

    public Route_plan createRoute_plan(long id_route, String route_plan_date,
            String route_name) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put(TableDEtails.COLUMN_ID_ROUTE, id_route);
        values.put(TableDEtails.COLUMN_ROUTE_NAME, route_name);
        values.put(TableDEtails.COLUMN_ROUTE_PLAN_DATE, route_plan_date);

        long insertId = database.insert(TableDEtails.TABLE_ROUTE_PLAN, null,
                values);
        Cursor cursor = database.query(TableDEtails.TABLE_ROUTE_PLAN,
                allColumns, TableDEtails.COLUMN_ID_ROUTE_PLAN_ID_AND + " = "
                        + insertId, null, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        // ProductBrand productBand = cursorToproductBand(cursor);
        Route_plan route_plan = cursorToRoute_plan(cursor);
        cursor.close();
        return route_plan;
    }

    public void deleteRoute_plan(Route_plan route_plan) {
        long id = route_plan.getRoute_plan_id_and();
        System.out.println("productBand deleted with id: " + id);
        database.delete(TableDEtails.TABLE_ROUTE_PLAN,
                TableDEtails.COLUMN_ID_ROUTE_PLAN_ID_AND + " = " + id, null);
    }

    public List<Route_plan> getAllRoute_plan() {
        List<Route_plan> Route_plans = new ArrayList<Route_plan>();

        Cursor cursor = database.query(TableDEtails.TABLE_ROUTE_PLAN,
                allColumns, null, null, null, null, null);

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            Route_plan route_plan = cursorToRoute_plan(cursor);
        //  ProductBrand productBand = cursorToRoute_plan(cursor);
            Route_plans.add(route_plan);
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        // make sure to close the cursor
        cursor.close();
        return Route_plans;
    }

    private Route_plan cursorToRoute_plan(Cursor cursor) {
        Route_plan route_plan = new Route_plan();
        route_plan.setRoute_plan_id_and(cursor.getLong(0));
        route_plan.setId_route(cursor.getLong(1));
        route_plan.setRoute_name(cursor.getString(3));
        route_plan.setRoute_plan_date(cursor.getString(2));


        return route_plan;
    }

}
```

**tabledetails**

```
public class TableDEtails {

    public static final String TABLE_ROUTE_PLAN = "table_route_plan";



        /** This data related to route plan table **/
        public static final String COLUMN_ID_ROUTE_PLAN_ID_AND = "column_id_route_plan_id_and";
        public static final String COLUMN_ID_ROUTE = "column_id_route";
        public static final String COLUMN_ROUTE_PLAN_DATE = "column_route_plan_date";
        public static final String COLUMN_ROUTE_NAME = "column_route_name";   

        // route_Plan table creating query
        public static final String ROUTE_PLAN_TABLE_CREATE = "create table "
                + TABLE_ROUTE_PLAN + "(" + COLUMN_ID_ROUTE_PLAN_ID_AND
                + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + COLUMN_ID_ROUTE
                + " integer," + COLUMN_ROUTE_PLAN_DATE + " text,"
                + COLUMN_ROUTE_NAME + " text)";

        // outlet table creating query


    }
```

**CLSQLiteHelper**

```
public class CLSQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {  


  private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "system.db";
  private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

  // Database creation sql statement


public CLSQLiteHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
  }

    @Override


public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {

          database.execSQL(TableDEtails.ROUTE_PLAN_TABLE_CREATE);


        }

  @Override
  public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    Log.w(CLSQLiteHelper.class.getName(),
        "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
            + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " +  TableDEtails.TABLE_USER);
    onCreate(db);
  }

}
```

I tried the above code to retrieve data from server and save data to a database to offline access. Downloading code from server is working fine but when the data is saved in to the database following error occurs

```
01-18 04:30:09.375: E/AndroidRuntime(20453): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: not an error (code 0)
01-18 04:30:09.375: E/AndroidRuntime(20453):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForChangedRowCount(Native Method)
01-18 04:30:09.375: E/AndroidRuntime(20453):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForChangedRowCount(SQLiteConnection.java:858)
01-18 04:30:09.375: E/AndroidRuntime(20453):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForChangedRowCount(SQLiteSession.java:754)
01-18 04:30:09.375: E/AndroidRuntime(20453):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeUpdateDelete(SQLiteStatement.java:64)
```

Comment: could you post your database implementation ?

Comment: I add the code in to my post

Comment: where you create table statement ??

Comment: Jsut see my new update.Sorry

Comment: could you check if database created in your project file system ?

Comment: I check my Android tab.Database is created

Comment: so if DB is create , the problem may be from you try to making more data inserting and you retrieve the inserted data in async way  , try to insert single row only to check if this is the problem or not

Comment: Actully my Json object have only 5 data

Comment: if you insert one object only (by making loop < 1) the error display with you ??

Comment: when i try to send 1 object.It gives The Following error.01-18 06:09:13.265: E/SQLiteLog(21810): (21) API called with NULL prepared statement
01-18 06:09:13.265: E/SQLiteLog(21810): (21) misuse at line 63314 of [00bb9c9ce4]

Comment: well this error because you close the connection after the loop the async task complete it's process , unless you still making query to retrieve the inserted row , try to close the connection with DB in onPostExecute and try again

Comment: still give ths same error